# Ehcache is not being refreshed by cacheDecorator

Tags: spring, caching, refresh, ehcache

I am using ehcache to refresh it from DB, but seems its not being refreshed.

ehcache.xml file ->

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" 
updateCheck="true"
monitoring="autodetect" 
dynamicConfig="true">

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>  

<defaultCache    
    maxElementsInMemory="100"  
    eternal="false"    
    timeToIdleSeconds="120"    
    timeToLiveSeconds="120"    
    overflowToDisk="true"    
    diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"    
    maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"    
    diskPersistent="false"    
    diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"    
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>  

<!-- The cache configuration for our Currency cache -->  
<cache name="cachename"  
    maxElementsInMemory="3000"  
    eternal="false" 
    timeToIdleSeconds="120"  
    timeToLiveSeconds="120"  
    overflowToDisk="true"  
    diskPersistent="false" >
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" synchronousWrites="true" />
    <cacheDecoratorFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.constructs.refreshahead.RefreshAheadCacheFactory"
  properties="name=myCacheRefresher,
  timeToRefreshSeconds=180,
  batchSize=10,
  numberOfThreads=4,
  maximumBacklogItems=100,
  evictOnLoadMiss=true" />
</cache>  
</ehcache>
```

config.xml

```
<ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehcache" />
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
<property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache" />
</bean>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" >
<property name="configLocation" value="ehcache.xml" />
</bean>  
<bean id="cachingAttributeSource" class="org.springmodules.cache.annotations.AnnotationCachingAttributeSource" />
```

CatchFetch.java

```
@GET
@Path("/Mymethod")
@WebMethod(operationName = "mymethodforUI")
public List<Object> mymethodforUI() {

    LOGGER.info("Getting mymethod.");
    return dao.mymethod("keyname");
}
```

CacheDAO.java

```
@Cacheable(value = "cachename", key = "#key")
public List<Object> mymethod(String key) {
    List<Object> res -> a slow query getting from Db
    return res;
}
```

Question 1: The caching is working good for first 180 seconds, but after 180 seconds, the cache is supposed to refresh. That behaviour is not being reflected. Can someone figure out why ?

Question 2: Is there any way I can log the timestamps when the cache refresh occurs defined by cacheDecoratorFactory?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that you aren't getting UnsupportedOperationException stating that refresh-ahead not supported under transactions or with GAE?

Comment: No, I aint getting UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: Which version of ehcache you are using? it seems  diskPersistent is deprecated in the recent versions, I see both  diskPersistent="false" >
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" synchronousWrites="true" /> which is confusing

Answer (score 0):

In order to have refresh ahead working you need to have a [cache loader defined](http://terracotta.org/documentation/4.1/bigmemorymax/api/refresh-ahead). Otherwise, how do you expect the cache to know how to populate a mapping?

A setup without a loader should probably throw an exception as it will not work.